# labels: 3rd value becomes a "-"

Tags: chart.js

I've a problem with showing the **labels** on doughnut-charts.
If I only have 2 values, labels are shown correctly, but if I have more than 2 values for the 'labels' attribute the third value becomes a: "-"
[labels: problem with 3rd value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjD01.png)

I collect the values via PHP in my var '$close1', when I do a `print_r($close1)` I get:

```
["customer", "fb", "colo", "isam", "reseller"]
```

But in chartJS-script I've the following values:

```
["customer", "fb", "-", "colo", "isam"]
```

what can I do?

Comment: Post your chart rendering code.